# Render cells in engines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rails-cells

I have an app which uses an engine. I generated a cell inside this engine. When I try to render this cell in engine's view i get an error:

> Missing template user/display with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder,
>   :coffee], :formats=>[:html, :text, :js, :css, :ics, :csv, :xml, :rss,
>   :atom, :yaml, :multipart_form, :url_encoded_form, :json],
>   :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in:   *
>   "/.../authorisation/myApp/app/cells"

My cell's controller is in:

> "/.../authorisation/myEngine/app/cells/user_cell.rb"

and views in:

> "/.../authorisation/myEngine/app/cells/user/"

So, the application runs the right cell controller but tries to render cell view from myApp dir instead of myEngine dir. I managed to temporarily fix it by creating a symbolic link to cell's view folder, but it doesn't look very professional..

Is there a config file where I can specify where the application should look for cells?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update to cells-3.8.2, should fix this problem.

Comment: You're my hero! :) Thanks dude.